# How to display Object Names and their keys in a Table properly from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display object names and their key values from firebase in a table format properly by using map Function inside another map function to display my arrays.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import CustomHeader from '../CustomHeader';
    import firebase from '../../database/firebase';
    import Schedule_1 from './Schedule_1';
    import Schedule_1_d from './Schedule_1_d';
    import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
    
    var categories = []
    var categories1 = [];
    var data;
    export default class Bus_Schedule extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                dataArray: {},
                arrayList: [],
                menu1:[],
                menu2: [],
              };
    
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            firebase.database().ref('Schedule/Route-01/').on('value', querySnapShot => {
               data = querySnapShot.val() ? querySnapShot.val() : {};
    
               console.log("Data submit")
              let todoItems = {...data};
              console.log(todoItems);
              this.setState({
                dataArray: todoItems,
              });
            });
    
    
            ///
    
            // var data1 = [];
            // console.log("letter send");
            // firebase.database().ref('Schedule/Route-01/').once("value").then(snapshot => {
            //   var data1 = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
            //   console.log(data1);
              
            // })
            
            
    
            firebase.database().ref('Schedule/Route-01/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    
              console.log("        Again");
    
              // this.setState({
              //   menu1: snapshot.val()
              // })
    
              // const categories = []
              // var categories1 = []
    
              snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
                 const item = snap.val();
                  categories.push(item);
    
                const item1 = snap.key;
                  categories1.push(item1);
                
                  // Array1 = item;
                  // console.log(Array1);
                  // let item1 = snap.key ? snap.key : {};
                  // Array2 = item1;
                  
                 
                     
              });
    
              /// For object Values
            //   console.log("Values");
            //  console.log(categories);
            //   this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
            //     menu1 :categories
            // })
            // console.log(this.state.menu1);
             /// For object Names
             console.log("Names");
            console.log(categories1);
              this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
                menu2 :categories1
            })
            // console.log(this.state.menu2);
              
             
         }.bind(this));
    
          }
    
    
          empty()
          {
            categories1 = [];
            categories = [];
    
          }
          
        render() {
            let todosKeys = Object.keys(this.state.dataArray);
            
            return (
                <View
                style={styles.container}>
                <CustomHeader title="Bus Schedule" navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    
                <DataTable style={{ top: -12 }}>
                  <DataTable.Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue' }}>
                    <DataTable.Title style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}><Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>Route 1</Text></DataTable.Title>
    
                  </DataTable.Header>
                  
    ////Using map function inside a map function ///////
                  {categories1.map((item, key) => (
                    
                 
                  <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#D1FDFF' }} key ={key} id = {key}>
    
                    <DataTable.Row >
                      <DataTable.Cell style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: "bold" }} key ={key} id = {key}>{item}
                      </Text>
                      
                      {categories.map((item1, key1) => (
                        <View style ={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}  key ={key1} id = {key1}>
                          <Text  key ={key1} id = {key1} style ={{ marginLeft:5}}>{item1} </Text>
                          </View>
                      ))
                    }
    
                      </DataTable.Cell>
                      
                    </DataTable.Row>
    
                  </View>
                  )
                  )}
    
                </DataTable>

                {this.empty()}
              </View>
            );
        }
    }
    

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: '#FEF9E7',
            flex: 1,
        },
    
        appButtonText: {
            fontSize: 15,
            color: "#fff",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            alignSelf: "center",
            textTransform: "uppercase"
        }
    });
```

I am trying to display object names and their key values from firebase in a table format properly by using map Function inside another map function. But my table does not value properly, and my out is shown below.

[image]

Output

[image: Kindly Click to see my Output]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the `key` and the corresponding value on the right to it you don't need two maps. Just use the `key` and `value()` of the snap to get both data.

Change this parts of the code:

```js
snapshot.forEach(function (snap) {
  const item = snap.val();
  categories.push({ key: snap.key, data: snap.val() });
});
```

And this part to:

```js
{
  categories.map(({ key, data }, key) => (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#D1FDFF" }} key={key} id={key}>
      <DataTable.Row>
        <DataTable.Cell style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: "bold" }} key={key} id={key}>
            {key}
          </Text>

          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            key={`key_1`}
            id={`key_1`}
          >
            <Text key={`key_2`} id={`key_2`} style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
              {data}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </DataTable.Cell>
      </DataTable.Row>
    </View>
  ));
}
```

Comment: the {data} is not properly aligned even after applying alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'Column' in its View, And also applying textAlign: 'center' in the Text.